# change border of contenteditable div element when focus using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript for the editable div element.

```
 var div = document.getElementById('htmlelement');
 var ele = document.createElement('div');
 ele.setAttribute('id','inputelement');
 ele.style.display = 'inline-block';
 ele.style.border = 'none';
 ele.style.minHeight = '100px';
 ele.style.maxHeight = '100px;'
 ele.style.padding = '10px';
 ele.style.fontSize = '12px';
 ele.style.color = 'blue';
 ele.setAttribute('contentEditable','true');
 div.appendChild(ele);
 ele.focus();
```

Now after focus black border shows over the div area automatically.
I want to remove and change that border color, but I think CSS will not work for this. because div element is dynamically created by javascript.

**is any way to remove that black border or change that border color.**

i am tryijng to use css but not working because of dynamic element creation
like,

```
[contenteditable] {
   outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: CSS works all the time, dynamically created or not

Comment: Assuming that the correct element(s) is/are appropriately targeted by the selector, to follow on from Jeremy’s comment.

Comment: There is also a typo in your code. `ele.style.fontSize = '12px''` should be `ele.style.fontSize = '12px';`

Comment: but I want to change border color on the basis of condition, how it possible, like I want to change the border color to blue and when I hover mouse outside of div I want to invisible border of the div that is showing on focus.
is it not possible using javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you talk about "border" you mean "outline"? You can just set it to `none`.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('htmlelement');

var ele = document.createElement('div');
ele.id = 'inputelement';
ele.style.display = 'inline-block';
ele.style.border = 'none';
ele.style.minHeight = '100px';
ele.style.maxHeight = '100px;';
ele.style.padding = '10px';
ele.style.fontSize = '12px';
ele.style.color = 'blue';
ele.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
div.appendChild(ele);
ele.focus();
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="htmlelement"></div>
```

Comment: I did the same but it's not working for the javascript created element, any solution for javascript?